# Changing the next button of softkeybord to Search

Tags: android

I want to change the next button of virtual keyboard to search button , is there any way to change the text of that next button to Search button.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
```

**Where to write ?**

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextSearch"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:imeOptions="actionSearch">
```

Comment: @manoj add it to edit text propery in xml . android:imeOptions="actionSearch"

Comment: thanx , it is working fine, can i change the text of "Next" button to "Search" button.

Comment: next button on the softkeyboard. i want text of that button should be "Search"

Comment: @manoj we can not change it to search text by default it shows Search Icon.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:imeOptions="actionSearch" //ADD THIS LINE TO YOUR REQUIRED EDITTEXT
        android:inputType="textPassword" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
```